# jquery form submit does not work in Safari and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I am creating a test application, where I give some questions to the user. While in the middle of the quiz, if the user chooses to leave the quiz, I give an alert stating that all the changes would be lost and the test would be submitted. I am doing that in the following way

HTML

```
<form id="testsForm" method="POST" action="/tests/submit">
<!--test questions here-->
</form>
```

Jquery

```
var submitted = false;saveBeforeUnload = false;
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
          if (!submitted) {
             saveBeforeUnload=true;
             return "You are about to leave this order form. You will lose any information...";
          }
}//alert given to the user to confirm if he/she wishes to leave the form
setInterval(function() {
          if (saveBeforeUnload) {
               saveBeforeUnload = false;
               $("#testsForm").submit();
          }
}, 500);//form submit logic
```

This logic is working on Firefox, but not on Safari and Chrome. Please help me out